# Printing a logo on a 3x2.3m

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-production

im new here so sorry if i do any mistakes in explaining. I've been doing graphic design works but explicitly for online and digital usage, never print. Now, im about to enter into the printing area of it all and i have a question;

Im supposed to print on a 3x2.3m surface (300x230 cm) just a logo on a specific height and width and i will attach a photo to clarify my question.

[image]

Now, am i on the right path or not?

Comment: How can we tell what path you’re on? All you’ve given us is a screen shot of a file opened in Illustrator and print requirements. It’s what you do from this point on that decides whether you’re on the right path.

Comment: That's the point, what you see is all that it has to be printed on the specific place (from 140cm to 230 in length) and the height is 105 to 126 cm in CMYK. What im actually asking is, is this what it's referred to 1:1 scale and since it's all vector i dont have to specify DPI right?

Sorry if all this sounds dumb, i've spent the last 4 hours reading things on the web but i still want to make sure to avoid mistakes and waste material..

Comment: No, DPI/PPI is not relevant when it’s all vector. There are many ways you can do it. Personally, I would place the logo into a 300 x 230 cm InDesign file, resize it to fit with the amount of margin you want on the final sign, and then export that to a PDF that you send to the printer.

Comment: Thank you! The printers in my area are cocky quite a bit, i literally asked for instructions so that i can make his job easier on him and the response i got was 'bring me print-ready file'. 

Thank you again and happy holidays!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to tell from the screenshot, so here`s a few things you should do:

- make the logo in real dimensions
- use vectors, not image  (when you go to outline mode, you should see the outlines of the logo, not an image box)
- make sure to define the logo in a color that will be printed. If black as on screenshot, define it as CMYK 0/0/0/100 or choose a single Pantone black from swatches. It depends on the type of media and printing technique you`ll be using
- the picture you plan to attach should be CMYK in a right color profile (ask the printers which they prefere)
- for billboards and similar large formats usually 150 dpi is enough resolution (or even less - 72 or 100) but, that`s also the information that dependes on purpose - to make sure, also ask the printer house

Hope to be of an assistance and best of luck!

Comment: Yes, we have had best results with preparing full size PDF files when ordering those huge digitally printed plastic-planes for outdoor-display. We are often worried about the internal communications of the print-shop; but a full-size PDF "speaks for itself": Somebody might miss the fact, that I want an A3 document blown up to A0 or bigger, but never the other way around. Or if an apprentice would accidentally print an order in only A4 size or A3 then not much money would be wasted and the precious relationship with the print-shop would not suffer.

Answer (score 1):

you can see your EXACT logo proportion by looking at Transform window. there mentioned are your x&y position and the exact Width and height. The printer will be the one responsible what area they will be using.

[image]

Comment: If the user sends a correct PDF file (say PDF/X-4) then there will be no ambiguity about "what area to use": size of logo and size of backing material (and even bleed) will be precisely defined and missunderstandings and trouble can be avoided. A precise PDF file will normally get all the way to the technician, but an order form with text-instructions or extra-requests might never make it to the person on the machine who will realize this order of a "billboard" or whatever that product is meant to become.

Comment: Yes your correct but note that always the last editor will always be the prepress designer who is responsible to adjust and communicate with the machine operators. Just mention also in a specific design the dimensions to be clear.